# Is requestAnimationFrame callback executed before reflow or repaint?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

mdn say

> The window.requestAnimationFrame() method tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser calls a specified function to update an animation **before the next repaint**. The method takes a callback as an argument to be invoked before the repaint.

rAF callback is called before repaint. But I'm not sure it is right.

Below is my test. As you see, rAF callback is called before "reflow" not repaint.

[image]

And I think it is right. Cause if rAF callback is called before repaint and the callback changes layout, rendering from rAF will be delayed for 16ms.

So I don't understand why mdn say rAF is called before repaint.
Is it right "before reflow"?

Comment: *"I don't understand why they said that the package will be delivered before 10am when it was delivered before 9am."* I don't see your problem/understand your question. Or are you asking if it's **guaranteed** that rAF will happen before reflow?

Comment: OK I understand. I mean it is not accurate. You mean "Before repaint" includes "Before reflow", is it right? I'm not sure this expression is best. I confused with it... How about "before operation process"?